# Twitter bottom cut off

Tags: html, css, twitter

I'm having a problem with the embedded twitter feed bottom being cut off and I can't see why that is. I'm embedding it with

```
<div class="twitterdiv">
       <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/xxx" data-widget-id="458185945217388544" height="400" data-link-color="#532427">Tweets by @xxx</a>
       <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
</div>
```

And in css just

```
.twitterdiv
{
     height: 400px;
}
```

But I should mention that this is placed in an outer div that has its width fixed. The strange thing is, when I go through css in console, I see that the width of the frame is set to the width of the outer div, if I disable the property and enable it again then it is shown ok.

[image: How it is]

[image: How it should be]

Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the CSS to

```
.twitterdiv {
height:500px;
width:500px;
}
```

or as you have mentioned

```
.twitterdiv {
height:320px;
width:320px;
}
```

Let me know if that does not work for you, if not then I'll try to figure it out for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. Per the [Twitter developer docs for embedded timelines](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines#dimensions), you can set the width and height directly. By default, it is set to 400. Try adding `height="425"` to your `a` tag as so when calling the widget:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline"
  height="425"
  href="https://twitter.com/twitterdev"
  data-widget-id="YOUR-WIDGET-ID-HERE">
Tweets by @twitterdev
</a>
```

This fixed it for me.